# The difference between various typedefs of structures

Tags: c, struct, typedef

[image: Type1]
[image: Type2]

i was wondering as to what is the difference between these two definition of structures one having the structure name(Books) and its instantiation(Book)
while the other has only the instantiation(complex).

Comment: you can't reference the struct as `struct Complex` in the second version, because the struct is anonymous, so the tag never enters the namespace

Comment: `Books my_struct;` vs `struct Complex my_struct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, you can declare or define variable of that type by

```
struct Books b;
```

or

```
Book b;
```

In the second version, you only can use

Complex c;

Note: both `Book` and `Complex` are type names.

Another difference, pointed out by @Rikayan Bandyopadhyay, in the first version, you can include a pointer element that can point to the same structure, which element will have type `struct Books *`, but you cannot do that in the second version.

Comment: Not only that. In the second version, pointers to the same structure cannot be declared inside it.